# Simple class definition example and callback error

Tags: javascript, class, callback

Coming from a C# and Java background it's been difficult trying to do class definitions with public/private methods, public/private members, and so on, in Javascript.

I have a simple example here showing Person.js and PersonTest.js.  There's a callback in the `start()` method because in my actual application there's a RESTful HTTP call in there that will use a callback (which is failing with the following error: `TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function`.

I have a few questions with which hopefully someone can help:
1) why the 'callback' argument must be a function error?  I've done `console.log(callback)` from within the method and it shows `[Function]`.

2) How do I keep this.name, this.age, this.debug from being accessible?

3) How do I keep `start(callback)` from being accessible?

Person.js

```
'use strict';

class Person {   
  // Methods 
  log(msg) {
    if (this.debug) console.log(msg);
  }

  start(callback) {
    var self = this;
    this.log("starting");
    console.log(callback);
    setTimeout(callback(true, null));
  }

  speak(msg) {
    this.log(msg);
  }

  // Constructor 
  constructor(name, age, debug) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.debug = debug;

    var self = this;
    this.start(function(data, err) {
      console.log("data: " + data);
      console.log("err: " + err);
      if (data) {
        self.log("started successfully");
      }
      else { 
        self.log("unable to start");
      }
    });
  } 
};

module.exports = Person;
```

PersonTest.js

```
const Person = require('./Person.js');
let p = new Person("henry", 50, true);
p.speak("foo");
```

Comment: Simple solution: you don't. There is no member accessibility in javascript. Don't try to fight it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a `callback` to `setTimeout` like this `setTimeout(callback(true, null));` you actually invoke it before passing. So you pass a result of a `callback`. Instead you need to do something like this

```
setTimeout(() => callback(true, null));
```

or

```
setTimeout(callback.bind(context, true, null));
```

According to your questions:

you can't keep class props and methods private in js. There is a convention of making others know that these are better not be used as they mean internal implementation - `this._prop` or `this._method`. If you really want to make those variables inaccessible you should make them a variables of your module so they are scoped with the module.

```
var name = '';

class Person {}
```

But that is obviously is not the case for a class as this variable is not going to be dynamic and stay with an instance of that class.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Would you know how to do items 2 and 3 or would it be more appropriate for me to accept this answer and start another question?  Thanks!

Comment: I'll answer that in a while)

Comment: Symbols are not private. They are hidden from `for in` loops, but they are not undiscoverable. Please do not suggest abusing them.